# Using speedglm on a data frame with a deleted factor

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to use the `speedglm` package for R to estimate regression models. In general the results are the same as using base R's `glm` function, but `speedglm` delivers unexpected behavior when I completely remove a given factor level from a data.frame. For example, see the code below:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100), x1=gl(5, 20)) 
dat2 <- subset(dat1, x1!=1)

glm("y ~ x1", dat2, family="gaussian")
Coefficients:
(Intercept)          x13          x14          x15  
    -0.2497       0.6268       0.3900       0.2811 

speedglm(as.formula("y ~ x1"), dat2)
Coefficients:
(Intercept)          x12          x13          x14          x15  
    0.03145     -0.28114      0.34563      0.10887           NA
```

Here the two functions deliver different results because factor level `x1==1` has been deleted from `dat2`. Had I used `dat1` instead the results would have been identical. Is there a way to make `speedglm` act like `glm` when processing data like `dat2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Droplevels I think is the key.

`str(droplevels(dat2))` vs. `str(dat2)` - even though `x1==1` is dropped it's still listed in the factor levels

So `speedglm(as.formula("y ~ x1"), droplevels(dat2))` should equal `glm("y ~ x1", dat2, family="gaussian")`

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior for glm with a factor independent variable is to use the *first* non-empty level as a reference category.  It appears that speedglm is treating the *last* level as the reference category.  To get comparable results, you can use `relevel` in the call to glm:

```
 set.seed(2)
 dat1 <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100), x1=gl(5, 20)) 
 dat2 <- subset(dat1, x1!=1)
 glm(y ~ relevel(x1,"5"), dat2, family="gaussian")

 Coefficients:
   (Intercept)  relevel(x1, "5")2  relevel(x1, "5")3  relevel(x1, "5")4  
     -0.27163            0.27135            0.36688            0.09934  

speedglm(as.formula("y ~ x1"), dat2)
 Coefficients:
 (Intercept)          x12          x13          x14          x15  
     -0.27163      0.27135      0.36688      0.09934           NA
```